# transform each row to several columns dataframe Pandas DataFrame

Tags: numpy, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe,whose every row consists of a list of indexes (one column named "Indexes" which has a comma separated string of value):

'Indexes'

'1,4,6,3,2,5,6,8'

'1,7,5,10,23,50'

I want to use apply in order to create a new matrix (DataFrame?), whose every row, has 1s at the values listed in the respective row in the original dataframe, and 0 elsewhere.  Assume that i know the number of new columns, as i have the min and max indexes (say 0 and 10). I can do it using iterrows/itertuples and construct a new matrix, but is there a more efficient way of doing that? I have a matrix of 1Million rows, but even at 100k this quite a long time.

[EXAMPLE]:

i'll an example and desired output for ease of understanding:

assume MAX_INDEX = 4 and MIN_INDEX=0:

for input:

'1,3,2,4'

'0,1'

the output will be 5-column matrix with two rows as follows:

0 1 1 1 1

1 1 0 0 0

[EDIT]
question remains - although i figured out it was very slow just because i created the new matrix using append, instead of allocating the memory a-priori and only inserting new rows. so one solution is:

```
m=np.empty(shape=[df.shape[0],numFeatures])
i=0
for row in df.itertuples():
    idxs = row[4] # column of peattributes
    idxs = map(lambda(x):int(x),idxs.split(','))
    r=np.zeros(numFeatures)
    r[idxs] = 1
    m[i,]=r
    i+=1
```

thanks,
Dan

Comment: Can you show us your desired output, based on the example you provided?

Comment: Thanks. Please update the original question.

Comment: Can you put this information in the original question? There is an edit button under it. It will be easier to read.

Comment: yes, sry about that. editted.

Comment: I'd be curious to see speed comparisons with your solution (I couldn't make your code work to do it myself...).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: It is much faster (four times) to check whether a string representing the integer is in the original string:

```
rng_str = [str(i) for i in range(MIN_INDEX, MAX_INDEX+1)]
s = df['Indexes'].apply(lambda row: [int(i in row) for i in rng_str])
pd.DataFrame(s.tolist())
```

Note: the last step converts from a Series of lists to a dataframe. It is faster to do it at the end rather than inside `apply`.

---

**Original answer below**:

I have a solution, I'd be curious to know if it performs faster than yours. The first step is to convert the string to list:

```
df['Indexes'] = df['Indexes'].apply(lambda s: [int(x) for x in s.split(',')])
```

I can then use the `apply` function to generate your output row by row:

```
rng = range(MIN_INDEX, MAX_INDEX+1)
df.apply(lambda row: [int(i in row['Indexes']) for i in rng], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
1    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```